# How to treat self-answered questions which do not reveal a real solution?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I'm seeing more and more (although I'm sure this has been around for a while) self-answered questions of the type:

Q: Can't find what's wrong in this bit of code

A: Oh, sorry, never mind, it's in another part altogether.

Examples:

- [SQLite3 - Library routine called out of sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546689/sqlite3-library-routine-called-out-of-sequence)
- [Database is locked -sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500635/database-is-locked-sqlite3)

What's the procedure/preventive measure here? I mean, that first one got answered by the poster in the same hour. It's not malice, but it *is* clutter...

Comment: That first one reads like a diary. Will he do another answer for his new findings?

Comment: @litb: Dear diary, today I fixed a bug. Also, I think Suzie from accounting likes me. :D

Comment: Kind of a misleading title... it's not really about self-answered questions, it's about questions that are unanswerable by others, which happens to be largely a subset of self-answered questions.

Comment: @Popular Demand: I gave that some more thought and I see what you mean. The question is only unanswerable through lack of the provided code (example 1 really just has the function call and the answer). Not quite sure how I'm gonna word that...

Comment: I meant: example 1 really just has the function call and the *error message*.

Comment: @MPelletier, nice title edit.

Comment: @Popular Demand, anything to prove that I succumb to peer pressure, not popular pressure. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)(s):

> It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

Self-answered questions generally aren't really harmful and sometimes they can even be helpful to other users, particularly those that are searching the broader internet with a similar issue.

Sometimes the post might be closed as too localized if it were a very simple user error.  You could also leave a comment encouraging the user to delete their question if it doesn't benefit the community in any way.

In the case of "Never mind, I figured it out" questions, I would do any or all of the following

- Leave a comment asking the user to delete his question,
- Leave a comment asking the user to post his solution as an answer, and/or
- Vote to close (and possibly revisit a few days later and vote to delete).

Comment: Seconded: Self-answered questions are fine, as long as they conform with SO's other rules. Seeing as no reputation is gained for self-answering a question (except for upvotes on the content, which is perfectly legitimate) there is no possibility of misuse, either.

Comment: I agree. Yet it would be great for the answer to be more than "never mind, it's in another part altogether". Obviously there is a lesson in each found error. As the two examples linked in the question do, explain the real cause. It might be helpful to others.

Comment: @Ralph: You're right, I've seen answers/updates like "Never mind" before.  I've updated my answer with what I would do in those situations.

Comment: If I find the answer to my own question I post it so that others can benefit from it. It's just helping the community.