# Dealing with self-answers where the OP admits that the problem was elsewhere

Tags: discussion, flags, self-answer

I just came upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871954/507519) by the OP of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6871839/507519):

> Sorry for this, I actually see now that me problem was from something ells in my app and not what I was thinking it is. Sorry for wasting time

That's it. No explanation, no additional information, nothing. This answer came after a round of edits in the question that may or may have not invalidated the answers already posted - I am not qualified to judge, but there are some complaints in the comments about this, which may have prompted the apology in the last sentence.

What, if anything, should I do in cases like this, where the OP of the question answers with an otherwise useless "sorry, my bad" post?

- **Flag the answer as "Not an answer"**

  The "answer" is most certainly not an answer, since apparently there was no question in the first place. At least, it is not an answer that could help future readers solve a similar problem. It also contains no additional information of any kind. On the other hand, it *does* provide a form of closure to this thread, even if it is an answer of the [PICNIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error) variety.
- **Vote for the question to be closed**

  Done, as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89948/153998) - in my opinion, the question wasn't *elaborate* enough to worth salvaging.
- **Flag the whole question and ask for deletion**

  The OP admitted that the problem was elsewhere, which invalidates the question and turns it into noise. In addition, future readers might get misled if they do not notice that final post by the OP. Yet, there are two answers that may be useful to them.
- **Add a comment asking the OP to delete the question**

  This was suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61952/153998), but its does have the same potential issues as flagging the whole question - the only thing that changes is who would do the deletion.
- **Leave it alone**

  Well, there's always the easy way out :-)

Comment: See also [How to treat self-answered questions which do not reveal a real solution?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61950/how-to-treat-self-answered-questions-which-do-not-reveal-a-real-solution)

Comment: @PopularDemand: I already saw that one :-) The problem here is that the self-answer practically invalidates the question, making it unanswerable.

Comment: Well, apparently alternative (n + 1) is to post on Meta hoping to harvest close votes...

Comment: Yeah... but if you do that too often, you'll find the close votes being aimed at your posts.

Comment: @PopularDemand: well, I expect my rate of meta-questions to go down as I get more familiar with the intricacies of reviewing :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vote to close as Too Localized.  He had a problem (possibly not what he described), found a solution (not given), and the posts can't ever help anyone else.  It's localized to him and that reason fits perfectly.

The answer **is** an answer, even if it's terrible a detail-free.  Not An Answer is reserved for things that are entirely unrelated, for things that should be comments, additional questions, and so on, not bad answers.

The question doesn't need to be deleted unless it's actively harming the site.  Examples of questions that need to be deleted (or at least locked with a warning):

- Wildly upvoted questions that are nonetheless off-topic (they encourage more of the same)
- Questions that have sparked flame wars that won't cool down
- Spam, downright offensive crap, illegal activities

Comment: +1 for "The question doesn't need to be deleted unless it's actively harming the site". That's actually a pretty good guideline - is it mentioned (semi-)officially somewhere?

Comment: @thkala I'm not actually sure. I just kind of picked it up through observation I guess :P

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware the "too localized" close reason mentioned in the answer preceding this one no longer exists.

If the problem was elsewhere, and that "elsewhere" is completely outside the domain of information convered by the question post such that nobody who read the question post could find that elsewhere-problem *without guessing*, one can use the "needs details / clarity" close reason.

Alternatively, some Stack Exchange sites have the community-specific close reason "not reproducible or caused by typo", or "needs debugging details". That would also be an appropriate close reason.

Comment: @Braiam I don't know why I didn't even think of that. That's a good answer. I have updated the answer post. Thanks!